# What is a relation $R$ composed with the null relation $\emptyset $? Is this composition also the null relation?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, relations

I understand the null relation ($\emptyset \subset A \times B)$ is simply the relation that relates NO element of set $A$ to any element of set $B$.

But what about in the context of composition? For example, if a relation $R$ maps from $C$ to $A$ (i.e. $R \subset C \times A$), then what is $R \circ S $, if $S$ is the empty relation?

Would $R \circ S$ also be the empty relation? So $R \circ S = S$? Because $R$ relates no elements of $C$ to $B$?

Note that here I'm defining a composition of relations to first "apply" the outer relation, in this case $R$, then apply the inner relation, in this case the null/empty relation.

Comment: Yes, composition of a relation with the empty relation results in the empty relation.  That is because any element in the composition of $R\circ S$ would be of the form $(c,b)$ where $c\in C$ and $b\in B$ such that there exists an $a\in A$ such that $(c,a)\in R$ and $(a,b)\in S$., but since there are no examples of any such $b$ there clearly are no such pairs in the composition.

Comment: @JMoravitz It helps to see a formal way of thinking about this, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Empty sets are always fun.

Let's take an element $(x,y)$ of $R\circ\varnothing$.

This means that there exists an element $z$ such that $(x,z)\in R$ and $(z,y)\in\varnothing$.

...

$(z,y)\in\varnothing$...

...

that's absurd!

---

So the premise is false: we cannot take an element of $R\circ\varnothing$.

This means that $R\circ\varnothing=\varnothing$.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you!